# How to return a field from a ScoredDocument in GAE Search API - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-search-api

I'm having trouble getting a specific document field out of a ScoredDocument. This must be very simple, but the documentation doesn't seem to cover it.

I've properly created an index, Documents in the index and searched the documents with results. The Documents just have a title property and a note property. How do I get the title or the note out? This is the server code:

```
class SearchHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    index = search.Index(name="myIndex")
    query_string = "dog" 
    try:
        results = index.search(query_string) 
        logging.info(results)
        self.response.out.write("""<html><body>
        Here are the results from the search for "dog":""")
        # Iterate over the documents in the results
        for note in results:
            self.response.out.write(note.fields)
            self.response.out.write(note.fields.title) # HERE IS PROBLEM
        self.response.out.write("</body></html>")
    except search.Error:
        logging.exception('Search failed')
```

The output without trying to get the title is correct and I get a ScoredDocument field:

```
[search.TextField(name=u'title', value=u'A note with a dog'),     search.TextField(name=u'note', value=u'hamster'), search.DateField(name=u'updated', value=datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 10, 0, 0)), search.DateField(name=u'created', value=datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 10, 0, 0))]
```

The error for trying to get the title this way is this:
    in get self.response.out.write(note.fields.title)
    AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'

Can anyone help with this?
Thanks

Comment: you should construct a response that can be written to the write method in a single go, it won't work to put it together like that piecemeal. Append to a string perhaps then output that.

Comment: Constructing the response doesn't seem to be the problem.  When I removed the response bit, I get the same error while trying to get the value of 'title': 'list' object has no attribute 'title'. I specifically need a call to get the value of 'title' out of a list of search fields like search.TextField.

Comment: Absolutely. I should have noted it as a separate issue, it won't solve your problem but it will solve a later problem you'll have if you keep doing that :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i believe it should be

```
note.field('title').value
```

Comment: That's the stuff. THANKS!

Comment: Is there any reason why this is no listed in their documentation? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/documentclass#Document_fields